# JavaFX Scene builder stopped working

Tags: crash, javafx, scenebuilder

Immediately after start of Scene builder this application stops working. OS will just shows popup with message: SceneBuilder.exe stopped working...

I'm using the latest Scene builder 1.1 on Windows 8.1, newest JDK 7 and eclipse Kepler.
I tried Scene builder 2.0 as well, but almost the same result, only difference is that it never shows any message, it just won't start at all.

If I create FXML file in project and try to open it with Scene builder, the same result will occur.

Is there anybody with similiar experience?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar strange problem. Suddenly all FX stopped showing altough I changed the code in all ways, also copied and pasted an example code in Oracle website with no luck. Restarted the computer and went well. Don't know what happened but I guess some bug.

Comment: I fix my issue with complete reinstall of OS (I had other problems with drivers) and reinstalling of all necessary components to run the Scene builder, till now I dont know what causes that problem but now it's working

Answer (score -1):

my scene builder stopped working and I installed scene builder from a different maker (gluon)

problem solved (for me)